# Android SQLite Database After delete table, will the id starts from 1?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a doubt that if i delete the table using following statements,

```
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.delete(date_difference, null, null);
```

then if i'm inserting a row as a fresh and first record into the table, will the id primary key auto increment of the records starts from 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has
>   a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.
>   The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is
>   one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert.
>   **If the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used.** If the largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer
>   (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive
>   candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously
>   used.

So yes, after you delete the table, IDs will start from 1

http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 2):

The documentation provided states that that delete method is a:

```
Convenience method for deleting rows in the database.
```

The syntax is:

```
int delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Therefore it won't start from 1 again. It'll continue on from the last increment. If you deleted the whole table, then re-created it, the increment would begin at 1.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite keeps track of the **largest ROWID that a table has ever held using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence"**. The sqlite_sequence table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created**.
 The content of the sqlite_sequence table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements**. But making modifications to this table will likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes.

So when you delete your table and you re-create it, you should make the SQLITE_SEQUENCE restart from 0.

You should do something like this :

```
Delete from date_difference;    
Delete from sqlite_sequence where name='date_difference';
```

Care because the field `'table name'` in where clause is case sensitive.

Read [this](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Define the primary key field as

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 1
```

Then remove the code if you are doing insertion of any value for the primary key field like following

```
values.put(KEY_PRIMARY, object.getIntegerValue());
```